# Is ThinkBook 14s Yoga Gen 2 compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, yoga-2

I see on the Ubuntu Page that Ubuntu 20.04 is compatible with the model "Lenovo ThinkBook 14 Gen 2 ITL/15 Gen 2 ITL", but does this include the "ThinkBook 14s Yoga Gen 2" model?

Comment: No, both hardwares are basically the same (16gb ram, intel icore7, 512 ssd, etc.), I was just making sure since the exact name does not appear on the certification page. Also, I saw this question where ubuntu failed on that hardware, but that person installed the 22.04 version https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435237/ubuntu-22-04-installation-usb-killed-two-m2-ssd-drives

Comment: Ubuntu isn't capable of killing hardware, at least not acutely. *Even if* there was some worst case scenario where there was some bug that caused excessive writes or caused file system errors or otherwise abused memory or CPU resources, it would take a very long time for that to actually damage hardware. Akin to eating a cheeseburger every day for the rest of your life. Not great for the system but it's not going to cause it to fail immediately. If the system meets the minimum hardware requirements, then it will run Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see how the linked question "Will my device work with Ubuntu? " answers this one. "Try it out" is not the solution for everyone. Maybe you can, but you shouldn't and shouldn't have to order devices and test around until one works.
I don't think space is so precious here that we cannot share experiences with particular devices.
I would have been happy if I had found this question answered before I bought the device.

Answer (score 1):

I have it here. Everything I tested works OOTB.

- Keys
- Wifi
- Cam
- Audio (Microfone does not sound great, though, but haven't tested much)
- Touch screen
- Pen (though I have not tested angle and pressure)

Screen rotation does NOT work for me yet, but the hardware is recognized:

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.SensorProxy --object-path /net/hadess/SensorProxy
```

and reports changes. This seems to be a higher level issue that is no limitation of the hardware.

Feel free to ask if you are interested in anything else in particular.

EDIT: Screen autorotate currently only seems to work with Xorg, not Wayland and Maliit, the Plasma virtual keyboard, seems to prevent my user from logging in. GNOME currently seems to be the better choice, but not for obvious hardware reasons.

EDIT2: I noticed substantial battery drain (like, dead after a week) despite the device being powered off (shutdown -h). Disabling FastBoot and Always-on USB in UEFI seems to have fixed this. (I don't know which one, do not need either so am not going to test for now.)